# Create an RSS feed for Wordpress using custom meta for custom post types

Tags: wordpress, rss, custom-post-type

I'm trying to find information on creating my own custom rss feed for my custom post types in Wordpress.

The way I have set up my custom post types mean that the 'title' can be duplicated (although I fixed this for  tags before anyone mentions it!).

Anyway, what I'm looking for is to display my title and custom meta for each of the feed's items but I just can't find any info.

Can anyone give me any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer quite easily...

1. Create a new template (i.e. feeds/my-new-feed.php)
2. Copy the code from wp-includes/feed-rss2.php into this new template
3. Do whatever it is you need to do to display whatever you want to.
4. Create a new page which uses that template

Hope this helps someone else.